# Substantivation d'éléments de l'emblème national pour le désigner : couleur, forme, nombre ?

Tags: adjectifs, pluriel, substantivation, botanique

Au [Canada](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/quiz/jeux-quiz-canada-fra.php) et au [Québec](http://www.drapeau.gouv.qc.ca/jeu/jeu.html), on a des [drapeaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_drapeaux_canadiens) à deux couleurs et un substantif qui réfère à ce qui apparaît sur ces drapeaux, soit la *feuille d'érable* et la *fleur de lys*, respectivement : **l'[unifolié](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/unifoli%C3%A9/80563?q=unifoli%C3%A9#441912)** (hérald.: « de gueules, au pal canadien d’argent, chargé d’une feuille d’érable du premier. ») et **le [fleurdelisé](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fleurdelis%C3%A9/34117?q=fleurdelis%C3%A9#431445)** (hérald.: « d'azur à la croix d'argent cantonnée de quatre fleurs de lys du même »), tous deux noms masculins du 20<sup>e</sup> sans doute basés sur des [emplois](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=l%27unifoli%C3%A9%2Cle%20fleurdelis%C3%A9%2Cunifoli%C3%A9%2Cfleurdelis%C3%A9&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cl%27%20unifoli%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cle%20fleurdelis%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble%20fleurdelis%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLe%20fleurdelis%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunifoli%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfleurdelis%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) plus anciens en adjectif (par exemple *fleurdelisé(e)*, att. 1502 au *DHLF* ; [*unifolié*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/unifoli%C3%A9) etc.). On peut facilement les imaginer au pluriel avec un *s* et l'article correspondant (*les*).

---

Qu'en est-il en France, en Belgique, et ailleurs dans la francophonie ? A-t-on un emploi en substantif pour son emblème national, dont l'usage serait plus ou moins comparable à celui de « drapeau du/de la [nom de pays] », mais qui permettrait de se passer du mot *drapeau*, et qu'on pourrait aisément retrouver dans une phrase du genre de celle-ci :

> [Article] [**nom**] *flottait/battait* etc. [préposition] ...

et qu'en serait-il du pluriel de ce substantif ? Un adjectif se rapportant au nombre de couleurs ne peut-il faire l'objet d'un emploi utile seul en substantif ; y préfère-t-on le nom des couleurs directement ou une autre référence ; y a-t-il une brève leçon à tirer sur l'emploi en substantif de l'adjectif selon qu'on regarde l'emblème sous l'angle de la couleur, de la forme ou du nombre ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En France, il y a un adjectif qui symbolise la nation: *[tricolore](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tricolore)*. Cet adjectif est très souvent utilisé comme synonyme de *français*. En pratique, *tricolore* a plus souvent le sens de *français* que le sens premier *ayant trois couleurs*. Le drapeau français est « le drapeau tricolore », même si le drapeau belge est « un drapeau tricolore ».

Dans un contexte historique (à partir de la Révolution et pendant environ un demi-siècle, jusqu'à ce que la monarchie absolue devienne politiquement improbable), *tricolore* peut désigner soit spéciquement les partisans de la république, soit tous ceux qui conçoivent la nation comme émanant du peuple (qu'elle soit dirigée par un [roi des Français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_des_fran%C3%A7ais), par un président ou par un empereur), par opposition à la fleur de lys qui symbolise la monarchie absolue de droit divin.

On trouve aussi cet adjectif sous forme de nom pour désigner quelque chose en rapport soit avec la France (« les tricolores » pour désigner l'équipe de France dans un sport), soit avec le symbole de la nation française (« les tricolores » pour désigner des opposants à la monarchie absolue, ou plus spécifiquement des républicains). On peut aussi dire « le tricolore » pour désigner le symbole en lui-même ([« conserver le tricolore [par opposition au rouge] »](https://books.google.fr/books?id=twv511ho2AsC&pg=PT66&dq=%22le+tricolore%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiayZLO7LLOAhUsDcAKHVJIDuE4ChDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=%22le%20tricolore%22&f=false), [« avant d'être drapeau, le tricolore fut cocarde »](https://books.google.fr/books?id=2IaFCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&dq=%22le+tricolore%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRjpLK7bLOAhWmJ8AKHTHzDyg4FBDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22le%20tricolore%22&f=false)).

Mais lorsque *tricolore* qualifie un  objet qui symbolise la nation, par exemple un drapeau, on n'omet pas jamais l'objet. En français moderne, « le drapeau tricolore » n'est jamais abrégé en « le tricolore ». On peut dire qu'un bâtiment « arbore le tricolore » (même si c'est rare), mais pas que « *le tricolor bat au vent ». (Enfin, si, [Jacques Hébert l'a dit](https://books.google.fr/books?id=baIEAQAAIAAJ&q=%22le+tricolore+bat%22&dq=%22le+tricolore+bat%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9tc3J7rLOAhVmFMAKHeB8Bn4Q6AEIHDAA), mais [il est bien seul](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&q=%22le+tricolore%22#tbm=bks&q=%22le+tricolore+bat%22). Ce n'est pas une métonymie habituelle.)

Answer (score 1):

En France

- *le tricolore*
- *les tricolores*
- *tricolore* (adj)

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu dire « Le tricolore » pour « Le drapeau tricolore »